# ASP.Net DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChange not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following DropDownList control:

```
<asp:label runat="server" text="Filter by state: "></asp:label>
<asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="filterbystate" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="FilterByState">
    <asp:ListItem value="all" selected="True">All</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="ca" selected="False">California</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="co" selected="False">Colorado</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="id" selected="False">Idaho</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="ut" selected="False">Utah</asp:ListItem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

Here is the method:

```
protected void FilterByState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = e;
}
```

The method will not fire for some reason.  I select a different value and nothing happens.  What I am trying to do is reload the page passing in the state value so I can filter the results by it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Set `AutoPostBack=True` as an attribute of your DDL and it will automatically post back the selected index change event

Comment: Knew it was something simple.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to dropdown list aspx it will cause a request to be send to the server and your event will be fired.

```
AutoPostBack="true"
```

Comment: Knew it was something simple.  Thank you.

Comment: No problems, please mark useful answers as an accepted so that others would benefit as well.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set `AutoPostBack = True`

From [`ListControl.AutoPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx) property;

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether a postback to the server
>   automatically occurs when the user changes the list selection.

Answer (score 1):

`AutoPostBack="true"` and

write page load event

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   DDL_Designation_Bind();   
}
```

// Because `autopostback` properties fire load event then our `dropdownlist` rebind and always selected index 0 so  Not Rebinding `dropDownlist`